# Travis CI переключает репозиторий в Legacy интеграцию

Tags: github, travis-ci

Последний раз дело было так. 
Было два репозитория, один из которых был нормально прикручен через Github Apps, а второй - Legacy Service. Я удалил из гитхаба второй, чтобы попытаться прикрутить его с нуля как положено. **Первый не трогал**. Сменил токен (для gh-pages), запушил это всё заново из локального репа, наконец, прикрутил Travis CI Github Apps к gh-pages - и!.. Оба репа стали Legacy. Оба... один из которых я не трогал вообще.
Что такое?..

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того, чтобы прикрутить Github Apps, надо было ещё открутить устаревшую интеграцию в виде сервиса. Именно она навязывала Legacy. Открутил - проблемы нет.